# Getting undefined value through checkbox component

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am getting undefined in isChecked inside handleClick function . Can you please check what I am doing wrong here.
If I do console.log(selectedlistItems.includes(id)); I have getting true/false value.
I have use same logic to set isChecked  isChecked={selectedlistItems.includes(item.id)}

```
import "./styles.css";

import { useState } from "react";
import CheckBox from "./CheckBox";
import { list } from "./List";

export default function App() {
  const [listItems, setListItems] = useState(list);
  const [selectedlistItems, setselectedlistItems] = useState([]);

  const handleClick = (e) => {
    const { id, isChecked } = e.target;

    console.log(isChecked);
    console.log(selectedlistItems.includes(id));

    if (!selectedlistItems.includes(id)) {
      
      setselectedlistItems([...selectedlistItems, id]);
    } else {
      
      setselectedlistItems(selectedlistItems.filter((item) => item !== id));
    }
  };
  console.log(selectedlistItems);
  return (
    <div>
      {listItems.map((item) => {
        return (
          <>
            <CheckBox
              key={item.id}
              name={item.name}
              id={item.id}
              handleClick={handleClick}
              isChecked={selectedlistItems.includes(item.id)}
            />
            {item.name}
          </>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
}
```

```
const CheckBox = ({ id, name, handleClick, isChecked }) => {
  return (
    <input
      id={id}
      name={name}
      type="checkbox"
      onChange={handleClick}
      checked={isChecked}
    />
  );
};

export default CheckBox;
```

Comment: The `isChecked` value does not exist on the input element target, since it is targeting the input element inside the CheckBox component. You can access `checked` instead. This would also make sense, since it represents the actual checked state of the input.

Answer (score 1):

The e.target refers to the  element itself, not the properties you want to access. So you are actually accessing the element attributes, not the  properties you want to access. To fix this, you can send the id property to the handleClick.

Send the property to handleClick:

```js
onChange={() => handleClick(item.id)}
```

Tweak handleClick:

```js
const handleClick = (id) => {
  console.log(selectedlistItems.includes(id));

  if (!selectedlistItems.includes(id)) {
    setselectedlistItems([...selectedlistItems, id]);
  } else {
    setselectedlistItems(selectedlistItems.filter((item) => item !== id));
  }
};
```

Comment: ok thanks. But actually I need to store that checked value inside isChecked property, as I jhave multiple checkboxes. If I use this const { id, name } = e.target; I can access id and name property of Checkbox component but not isChecked why is it so?

Comment: For other readers, I see JB17 in the comment to OP post gave a great answer on this question :)